# SQL database update statement not working

Tags: java, android, sql

```
ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("select * from donor where username = '" +       username + "'");
        String type = rs.getString("bloodtype");
        System.out.println("the user's blood type is: " + type);
        String Updatesentence = "update bank set " + type +  " = " + type + " + 1 where name = '" + name + "'";
        System.out.println(Updatesentence);
        stat.executeUpdate(Updatesentence);
```

Guys I am trying to make an update to an SQL database with this code and although I am not getting an error somewhere the code does not work with the desired result. The

```
            System.out.println(Updatesentence);
```

is not printed and the update is not performed. I know there probably is somewhat of a syntax error on my String declaration, but I cannot work it out.

Comment: what is the correct column name? blood type or type? Instead if * give us columns name for both tables.

Comment: @Paresh the column on my database is called bloodtype. The type is the input argument of my class.

Comment: Have you tried to debug it and watched where the code stops running?

Comment: this should be ,
String Updatesentence = "update bank set " + type +  " = " + type + " + 1 where name = '" + name + "'";

String Updatesentence = "update bank set  type "+  " = " + type + " where name = '" + name + "'";

Answer (score 2):

You have this:

`String Updatesentence = "update bank set " + type +  " = " + type + " + 1 where name = '" + name + "'";`

So if the user's blood type is AB...

`update bank set AB = AB + 1 where name = 'JohnSmith'`

And that obviously won't work.  You need to indicate the column in the database you want to be updating.

Answer (score 1):

One of the most important things you need to remember when writing SQL statements, is to separate the query *literal* from the query *arguments*. This allows protection from [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and also makes it possible for the DB to reuse the query with different arguments (and "hard parsing" / optimizing the query only once). The way you do this with JDBC, is through [prepared statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html):

```
try (PreparedStatement queryPS = myConnection.prepareStatement(
        "select * from donor where username = ?");
     PreparedStatement updatePS = myConnection.prepareStatement(
        "update bank set bloodtype = ? where name = ?");) {

    queryPS.setString(1, username);
    ResultSet rs = queryPS.executeQuery();
    if (rs.next()) {
        String type = rs.getString("bloodtype");
        System.out.println("the user's blood type is: " + type);
        updatePS.setString(1, type);
        updatePS.setString(2, username);
        updatePS.executeUpdate();
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    // handle it
}
```

When you use prepared statements, you don't need to worry about concatenating the inputs into the query; they will be sanitized and injected automatically. If you're doing things the "wrong way", it's really easy to make a mistake when you construct the query piece by piece from different variables in your code, and this is exactly what happened with the misplaced `type` variable in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Your update statement is wrong. It should be :
String Updatesentence = "update bank set  bloodtype  = " + type + " + 1 where name = '" + name + "'" ;